# license keys generation method for software product

Tags: cryptography, licensing, rsa

We have a software database product that is delivered to a customer. The fees charged are based on a number of factors such as

1. number of users that can be created
2. number of database transactions etc

We wanted to give a license key whenever the user pays for some time duration. So the license key should contain such information about the duration of product, number of users/transactions allowed etc..

What is a cryptographically secure way of license key generation (that contains the whole information and can be read securely by our system at their end) to prevent user from any illegal usage.

I know about RSA as a method but how do I go about it? and are there any tools available that i should checkout?

Comment: Do you trust your customers to not try to tamper with the license key?

Comment: Here is a similar question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867670/generating-validating-license-key-for-c-sharp-server-control/14964340#14964340

Comment: @EmilVikström I want a solution that even if the tamper with the key they cant get access to the system. So answering your question, No i dont trust the customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate license files Public-Private key Cryptography, and using RSA.
Please look at this library, you can found this useful.
http://afewguyscoding.com/page/2/
This library people have also done survey, which will give you idea that how good this method works.

There is another github project using similar approach.
Visit https://github.com/starschema/slm4j

Comment: The solution I am looking for is a License Key generation similar to the process in windows whereby I provide a Key(25-40 characters) which contains the information required and it is entered at users end.
anyways thanks :)